# php - foreach loop - correct (most efficient way to handle a first case scenario )

Tags: php

I have a function that builds a MySQL query from the supplied arguments.  My current code is:

($args can be an empty array or up to a set of 5 field_names=>array_of_ids ...)

```
if( !(empty( $args )) )
{
    $flag = 0;
    $sql_append = '';

    foreach( $args as $field_name => $id_array )
    {
        if( $flag == 0 )
        {
            $where_connector = " WHERE ";
            $flag = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $where_connector = " AND ";
        }

        ${ $field_name . '_string'} = join(',',${ $field_name . '_ids'});
        $sql_append .= $where_connector . 'link_id IN ($ids)";
    }        
}
```

I'm self-taught and so constantly worry about best practices.  I seem to remember some sort of function that handles arguments, perhaps in a way that can be applied here more efficiently.  Any ideas?

Comment: What portion of the SQL string are you trying to construct? The WHERE clause? It's not clear from this code what's actually accomplished. For example, the $flag is never modified after the initial step.

Comment: You don't need to check `if (!empty($args))` before the `foreach`, because an empty array will simply skip the loop. Unless `$args` can be something like an empty string or `null`, you don't need the outer `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To neatly construct your WHERE $fieldname IN($ids) clauses from a $fieldname=>$id_array array, you can try this :)

```
function buildWhereIns(array $args)
{
    if(!is_array($args) || empty($args)) return ""; 

    $ids = array_map(function($item){ 
    return implode(',',$item);
    }, array_values($args));

    $fields = array_map(function($item,$id){ 
    return $item.' IN('.$id.') ';
    }, array_keys($args),$ids);

    return = count($fields) > 0 ? count($fields) > 1 ? " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $fields) : " WHERE " . array_shift($fields) : ""; 
}
```

Comment: `count($fields) > 0 ? count($fields) > 1 ?` can cause `readability` issue .... Nice anyway +1

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the larger issue here is that you should be using some sort of technique to protect your code against SQL injection. For example, PHP's built-in PDO classes provide a really easy way to do this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php.

In general, though, if you want a loop that behaves differently on the first or last iteration, your method isn't bad. The other obvious method is to just do the first (or last) iteration *outside the loop*, and then perform the iterations which are the same inside the loop body.